# react-native-picker won't populate data on edit form

Tags: react-native, state, dropdown, react-native-picker

I'm using `react-native-web` and for the Native side, I'm using `import { Picker } from '@react-native-picker/picker'`

I'm using a reusable form modal for create and edit. On web, the data populates just fine but on iOS for example, the drop downs don't get set correctly. I've created a reusable component that has `react-native-picker/picker` as it's child component. So for example I set state on form mount like this:

```
 const [languageAbility, setLanguageAbility] = useState<number>(
    childProfile?.languageAbility?.id || 0,
  )
  const [grade, setGrade] = useState<number>(childProfile?.grade?.id || 0)
```

and on my components, they are set up like this:

```
 <AccessibleSelect
              selectedValue={grade}
              options={childMenusData?.menus?.schoolGrades.map((sg) => ({
                label: sg.title,
                value: sg?.id,
              }))}
              onValueChange={(val: number) => setGrade(val)}
              label={t('ChildForms.Grade')}
              testID="grade"
              inputStyle={styles.selectStyles}
              tooltipText={isMobile ? 'What is a grade?' : ''}
              tooltipContent={t('ChildForms.WhatIsAGradeContent')}
              tooltipPlacement={'bottom'}
            />
          </View>
          {!isMobile && (
            <View style={styles.inputContainerHalf}>
              <Tooltip
                text="What is a grade?"
                content={t('ChildForms.WhatIsAGradeContent')}
                placement={'right'}
              />
            </View>
          )}
        </View>
        <View
          style={{
            flexDirection: isMobile ? 'column' : 'row',
            width: '100%',
            margin: 0,
          }}
        >
          <View
            style={[
              styles.inputContainerHalf,
              { marginRight: isMobile ? 0 : 30 },
            ]}
          >
            <AccessibleSelect
              selectedValue={languageAbility}
              options={childMenusData?.menus?.languageAbilities.map((la) => ({
                label: la.title,
                value: la.id,
              }))}
              onValueChange={(val: number) => setLanguageAbility(val)}
              label={t('ChildForms.LanguageAbility')}
              testID="languageAbility"
              additionalContainerStyles={{ paddingTop: 0, paddingBottom: 0 }}
              inputStyle={styles.selectStyles}
            />
          </View>
        </View>
```

And the actual Picker component (AccessibleSelect) looks like this:

```
  return (
    <View style={[styles.container, additionalContainerStyles]}>
 
      <Picker
        ref={refToAttachToInput}
        style={[
          Platform.OS === 'ios'
            ? styles.pickerIOS
            : [
                styles.picker,
                { borderColor, borderStyle: 'solid', borderWidth: 1 },
              ],
          inputStyle,
        ]}
        selectedValue={selectedValue}
        onValueChange={onValueChange}
        defaultValue={defaultValue && defaultValue}
        itemStyle={styles.pickerText}
        mode={isAndroid && 'dropdown'}
      >
        {options.map((o) => (
          <Picker.Item label={o.label} key={o.value} value={o.value} />
        ))}
      </Picker>

      <View
        style={[
          styles.bottomContainer,
          { justifyContent: fieldError ? 'space-between' : 'flex-end' },
        ]}
      >
        {!!fieldError && (
          <Text accessibilityLiveRegion="assertive" style={styles.errorText}>
            {fieldError}
          </Text>
        )}
      </View>
    </View>
  )
}
```

Comment: I would suggest you trying to split your code into small pieces, just use the basic example of the official doc for that picker and try that first in IOS, see how it works and start from there, usually something get mess when you do tests just at the end. 
Another key thing to do, is check the issues from the github repo for that module, and see if something is related to IOS picker issues

Comment: https://github.com/react-native-picker/picker/issues/341

Comment: I had to make selectedValue an integer for it to work. This is not necessary on Web. Have to `parseInt(value, 10)` for each `selectedValue.' Not sure why but it works now.